How to make a Prismoid in Three.js?
I'm using Three.js and I'm trying to make a pyramid, but with its top cut off, and its base is a rectangle, and the top is also a rectangle, but not in the same proportions.
Heres the pic from wikipedia, but I want it to allow for rectangle bases

I think the word for it is Prismoid, except in my case the base isnt going to be a square, but a rectangle. Another thing I want to do with this is make the top not centered on the base, allowing me to create things like Parallelepiped

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prismatoid
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped

I've looked into CylinderGeometry and PolyhedronGeometry, but they both require that the base sides are all the same length.
What's the most effective way of making these shapes?

vertex shader applied to a cube perhaps? Or maybe the Taper modifier from this library

It was a long complicated process figuring this all out, but I did it! Thanks to @Łukasz D. Mastalerz for his help!
heres the code:
function createGeometry(width, depth, height, widthTop, depthTop, posTop = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)) {

    //create geometry
    let bufferGeometry = new BufferGeometry();

    //create base points
    const w2 = width / 2;
    const d2 = depth / 2;
    let v0 = new Vector3(-w2, 0, -d2);
    let v1 = new Vector3(w2, 0, -d2);
    let v2 = new Vector3(w2, 0, d2);
    let v3 = new Vector3(-w2, 0, d2);
    //create top points
    const wt2 = widthTop / 2;
    const dt2 = depthTop / 2;
    let v4 = new Vector3(-wt2, height, -dt2).add(posTop);
    let v5 = new Vector3(wt2, height, -dt2).add(posTop);
    let v6 = new Vector3(wt2, height, dt2).add(posTop);
    let v7 = new Vector3(-wt2, height, dt2).add(posTop);
    // points
    let points = [
        v0, v1, v2, v3,
        v4, v5, v6, v7,
    ];

    //vertices
    const vertices = new Float32Array(
        points
            .map(p => [p.x, p.y, p.z])
            .flat(Infinity)
    );

    //indices
    const indices = new Uint32Array([

        //right
        0, 3, 7,
        7, 4, 0,

        //left
        2, 1, 5,
        5, 6, 2,

        //top
        7, 6, 5,
        5, 4, 7,

        //bottom
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0,

        //back
        1, 0, 4,
        4, 5, 1,

        //front
        3, 2, 6,
        6, 7, 3,

    ]);

    //width uv constants
    const widthOffset = posTop.x;
    const maxWidth = Math.max(width, w2 + wt2 + Math.abs(widthOffset));
    const widthDiffLeft = w2 - wt2 + widthOffset;
    const widthDiffRight = width - (w2 + wt2 + widthOffset);

    //depth uv constants
    const depthOffset = posTop.z;
    const maxDepth = Math.max(depth, d2 + dt2 + Math.abs(depthOffset));
    const depthDiffLeft = d2 - dt2 + depthOffset;
    const depthDiffRight = depth - (d2 + dt2 + depthOffset);

    //uv
    const uvs = new Float32Array([

        //right
        Math.max(0, (0 - depthDiffLeft) / maxDepth), 0,//BL
        Math.min(1, (maxDepth + depthDiffRight) / maxDepth), 0,//BR
        Math.min(1, (maxDepth - depthDiffRight) / maxDepth), 1,//TR
        Math.min(1, (maxDepth - depthDiffRight) / maxDepth), 1,//TR
        Math.max(0, (0 + depthDiffLeft) / maxDepth), 1,//TL
        Math.max(0, (0 - depthDiffLeft) / maxDepth), 0,//BL

        //left
        Math.max(0, (0 - depthDiffRight) / maxDepth), 0,//BL
        Math.min(1, (maxDepth + depthDiffLeft) / maxDepth), 0,//BR
        Math.min(1, (maxDepth - depthDiffLeft) / maxDepth), 1,//TR
        Math.min(1, (maxDepth - depthDiffLeft) / maxDepth), 1,//TR
        Math.max(0, (0 + depthDiffRight) / maxDepth), 1,//TL
        Math.max(0, (0 - depthDiffRight) / maxDepth), 0,//BL

        //top
        0, 0,
        1, 0,
        1, 1,
        1, 1,
        0, 1,
        0, 0,

        //bottom
        0, 0,
        1, 0,
        1, 1,
        1, 1,
        0, 1,
        0, 0,

        //back
        Math.max(0, (0 - widthDiffRight) / maxWidth), 0,//BL
        Math.min(1, (maxWidth + widthDiffLeft) / maxWidth), 0,//BR
        Math.min(1, (maxWidth - widthDiffLeft) / maxWidth), 1,//TR
        Math.min(1, (maxWidth - widthDiffLeft) / maxWidth), 1,//TR
        Math.max(0, (0 + widthDiffRight) / maxWidth), 1,//TL
        Math.max(0, (0 - widthDiffRight) / maxWidth), 0,//BL

        //front
        Math.max(0, (0 - widthDiffLeft) / maxWidth), 0,//BL
        Math.min(1, (maxWidth + widthDiffRight) / maxWidth), 0,//BR
        Math.min(1, (maxWidth - widthDiffRight) / maxWidth), 1,//TR
        Math.min(1, (maxWidth - widthDiffRight) / maxWidth), 1,//TR
        Math.max(0, (0 + widthDiffLeft) / maxWidth), 1,//TL
        Math.max(0, (0 - widthDiffLeft) / maxWidth), 0,//BL

    ]);

    //compile it together
    bufferGeometry.setIndex(new BufferAttribute(indices, 1));
    bufferGeometry.setAttribute('position', new BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));

    const sideCount = 6;
    for (let i = 0; i < sideCount; i++) {
        bufferGeometry.addGroup(i * sideCount, sideCount, i);
    }
    bufferGeometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;

    bufferGeometry = bufferGeometry.toNonIndexed();

    bufferGeometry.setAttribute('uv', new BufferAttribute(uvs, 2));
    bufferGeometry.attributes.uv.needsUpdate = true;

    //return
    return bufferGeometry;
}


first you have to define where the vertices are going to go (the vertices array).
then you have to define the faces (the indices array). make sure to use the right-hand rule when declaring the points. in this method, i declared the points in the same order in each face so it makes the algorithms easier to program later on.
after that come the uvs (the uvs array). this was the hard part. for each triangle, for each point, put 2 floats from 0 to 1 in the uvs array. The trouble is that up until now, we've been setting things using indexing, but the uvs require us to not use indexing (at least in my case). So to make it match, we have to call toNonIndexed() before we set the uvs.
There's a lot of code in the uvs array declaration, but they all result in a number between 0 and 1. I put special code in there to make it look natural when the top isnt centered and when its a different size than the base.

After that, compile it all together and you have a prismoid geometry that can also handle doing parallelepipeds.

If for some reason you do not want to create such a shape, e.g. in Blender (this seems to be the easiest solution to me). You can simply modify faces and vertices manually. Just play with the vertices to get the shape you want. Uncomment the vertices and you'll see what I mean...
const vertices = [
    new THREE.Vector3(-1.5, -1, -1),
    new THREE.Vector3(1.5, -1, -1),
    new THREE.Vector3(1.5, -1, 1),
    new THREE.Vector3(-1.5, -1, 1),
    new THREE.Vector3(-1, 1, -0.5),

    // Top rectangle 
    new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, -0.5),
    new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 0.5),
    new THREE.Vector3(-1, 1, 0.5)
];

// for example:

// vertices[1].y += 0.2;
// vertices[6].y += 0.2;
// vertices[4].y -= 0.2;
// vertices[7].y -= 0.2;

const faces = [
    [0, 1, 4],
    [1, 2, 5],
    [2, 3, 6],
    [3, 0, 7],
    [1, 0, 3],
    [3, 2, 1],
    [5, 2, 1],
    [5, 6, 2],
    [7, 6, 3],
    [7, 3, 0],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [4, 6, 7]
];

const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
const verticesArray = [];
vertices.forEach(function(vertex) {
    verticesArray.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
});
geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(verticesArray, 3));

const indices = [];
faces.forEach(function(face) {
    indices.push(face[0], face[1], face[2]);
});
geometry.setIndex(indices);

const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00, wireframe: true });
const pyramid = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(pyramid);


thanks for the answer man! it didnt solve my problem completely, but it gave me the head start i needed to get something working
